# Odoo 10: Changing the default search in tree view

Tags: python, search, view, default, odoo

I created a custom module which has a tree view.The top right search bar search my records using  ID by default . I want to search my records using "icc" field. 
I added  **{"search_default_icc":1}** 
but didnt work.
Below is my code:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="view_sim">
            <field name="name">Sim Details</field>
            <field name="res_model">simcard.simcard</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="context">{"search_default_icc":1}</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create new
                </p>
            </field>
    </record>
```

What should i write in the code ? Also is it possible to call a python function when search is triggered??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a search view, docs at: http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#search

Example:

```
<record id="simcard_piavita_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">simcard_piavita.simcard_piavita.search</field>
    <field name="model">simcard_piavita.simcard_piavita</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search">
            <!-- add all the needed field to use for search-->
            <field name="icc"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: This works!! Can i call a function when the search is triggered??

Comment: You can override the method search of the model to implement you custom domain or search

Answer (score 0):

You can add a search_view_id field on your action :

```
<field name="search_view_id" ref="id_of_the_search_view" />
```